# MySQL read only transaction can modify table

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to use read only transaction in MySQL and I'm confused how it can modify (insert to table ) and can alter table column ( DDL and DML). example :

```
SET @@transaction_read_only=true;
start transaction ;
insert into Table_NAME (ID,name) values (3,'test');
ALTER TABLE Table_Name MODIFY COLUMN name VARCHAR (1000);
commit ;
```

can anybody explain what is wrong here ?

---

Update: I'm using datagrip and I found the issue is with DataGrip from mysql shell this doesn't work :   `insert into Table_NAME (ID,name) values (3,'test');`

however this still work :

```
 ALTER TABLE Table_Name MODIFY COLUMN name VARCHAR (1000);
```

Comment: Is your transaction the first transaction after setting read only?

Comment: @Jacob the issue is with DataGrip not sure why it's not working, however the DDL still working from mysql shell with read only

Comment: have you tried SET @@session.transaction_read_only = true? the difference is for next transaction only vs for the whole session.

Comment: @Jacob this is not the issue I'm using only one transaction after it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ALTER TABLE will cause an implicit commit, so that that will be another transaction.

Don't put DDL in the transaction, it will make things complicated.

SET @@transaction_read_only=true; only works for the next transaction; while SET @@session.transaction_read_only = true is for the session.

Comment: I was just trying I expected that , DDL run commit directly. Thx